# XSLT - upper-case not working

Tags: browser, opera, xslt

I'm playing around trying to learn XSLT (client-side, for now). The following errors:

...with Opera 11 complaining that upper-case is not a function. I guess this means Opera 11 is running XSLT 1.0, which was before functions like upper-case were defined. How can I confirm this? Opera's spec doesn't mention XSLT, yet clearly it has a built-in processor.

Does any browser support XSLT 2.0?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: It looks like you didn't hear about [Saxon Client Edition](http://www.saxonica.com/ce/doc/contents.html)

Answer (score 1):

I found this in the Presto 2.8 (Opera 11's rendering engine) Web Standards [XML documentation](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto28/xml/)

> **XSLT, XPath and XSL-FO**
>
> Opera supports XSLT style sheets with the `<?xml-stylesheet?>` processing instruction; see Associating Style Sheets with XML documents Version 1.0. Opera supports XSLT 1.0 and XPath 1.0 with the following exceptions:
>
> - The namespace-alias element is not supported.
> - Opera does not support XSL-FO.

Regarding browser support for XSLT 2.0, to my knowledge no major browsers support it (although [there is fairly wide support for XSLT 1.0](http://www.w3schools.com/Xsl/xsl_browsers.asp))

[Here's a page for the web standards documentation](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto28/)

Comment: Thanks, guys, I will look into the Saxon thing. Apart from that, if you want to learn XSLT 2.0, I guess the only way is to use server-side rather than client-side XSLT?

Comment: @Mitya -- server side is probably your better option.  Another (small) consideration is that normally you'd use XML + XSLT to generate XHTML, which isn't supported in IE < 9.  It's a small potential roadblock to clientside